# "Correct" way to cast ALAssetRepresentation size (long long) to size_t for 32-bit devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, alasset, alassetlibrary

I've got the following code that pulls data from an `ALAssetRepresentation`.

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = ...;
size_t size = [representation size]; // 'size' returns a long long
uint8_t *bytes = malloc(size);
```

When building for 32-bit devices on iOS, I get the following warning.

[image]

Blindly casting the `long long` to a `size_t` works, but I don't know what the "right" way to handle this situation is. Would love to know how to best handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning to a type of `size_t`, cast the result as a `size_t`.

```
size_t size = (size_t)[representation size];
```

The only risk of this is that `representation size` could be a number larger than what will fit in a `size_t`. But if that happens, the value is too large to allocate memory for it anyway when running on an iOS device so that is a bigger problem than the loss in precision.